# Trying to access child objects in a nested form that uses fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a parent model called Account that has a Company.

The Account model uses the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company` helper.

I'm using a RESTful approach to creating an Account, that will / should also create a Company.

In my new action for the AccountsController, I have:

```
@account = Account.new
@company = @account.companies.new
```

When I fire up the new view, I can see both the account object and the company object using the `<%= debug... %>` function in the view.

In my create action for the AccountsController, I `render 'new'` if validation does not pass.

**Here's what's confusing me:**

When `render 'new'` is invoked, I no longer see the company object, but only the account object.

Where did the company object go and how do I get it back so I can access it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "create" must contain the line with "@company = @account.companies.new" if validation does not pass.

Comment: That did it!  Man, I've been at this for hours!  Thank you!

Comment: BTW, for total newbies like me, to access the child object (in my case "companies") I had to use: `@account.companies.first` since it's an array.